# Rails: Facebox link if condition is satisfied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, hyperlink, facebox

I want to display a facebox link when I click on a  element when a particular condition is satisfied.
I do not want the user to click if the condition is not satisfied. 
I am doing something like this to achieve it which is pretty ugly

```
<% if x == 5 %>
    <a id="something" href="http://www.some_weird_link.com" rel="facebox">
<% end %>
<div>
    <!-- Loads of HTML and erb code here which should be shown no matter what condition -->
</div>

<% if x == 5 %>
    </a>
<% end %>
```

Note that I have to put an if condition just so that the `</a>` does not come in my HTML when the condition is not satisfied. This looks bad.
Can you suggest me a better way of doing this ?

`link_to_if` is promising but then it wants me to put the link display text in the parameter which happens to be a big `<div>` in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried a few different cases, and this works (will not link if you pass the option :if => false, will create the link if you pass :if => true, or if you don't pass the if option at all)

Define the helper:

```
  def facebox( *args , &block )
    if !args.last.is_a?(Hash) || args.last.fetch(:if,true)
      link_to *args , &block
    else
      block.call
    end
  end
```

Once you have that helper, any time you want to use your facebox link method (which you might as well flesh out with all the special facebox arguments -- that rel, for example, could probably be moved into the helper to clean up your view)

Then you can do this in your view:

```
  <% facebox 'http://www.some_weird_link.com' , :id => 'something' , :rel => 'facebox' , :if => (x == 5) do %>
    <div>
      <!-- Loads of HTML and erb code here which should be shown no matter what condition -->
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<%= "<a id='something' href='http://www.some_weird_link.com' rel='facebox'>" if x == 5 %>
<div>
    <!-- Loads of HTML and erb code here which should be shown no matter what condition -->
</div>


<%= " </a> " if x == 5 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly this should do the trick:

```
<%= ((x == 5) ? (link_to 'facebook', 'http://www.some_weird_link.com', :id => 'abc', :rel => 'facebox') : '') %>

<div>
    <!-- Loads of HTML and erb code here which should be shown no matter what condition -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Sameera... Thanks for the reply. The problem is that the link_to text ('facebook' in your answer) is actually a big <div> .... </div> which had html+erb content.
So I could not use something like this.
Appreciate you help though :) Thanks!

Comment: Hi,

Then try something like this, 

create a helper method 

def my_link
  <create your html+erb and NOTE : create your link also inside this>
end

Ex: 
def my_link
  "<p>This is a huge text and it has a long string but it works as a link also if you click" +  <a href='url'>here</a> + "</p>"
end

and call it like this

<%= ((x == 5) ? (my_link : '') %>

The idea here is add your complexity to the helper

cheers

sameera

Comment: Please always check the preview window before submitting a post - this code was mostly invisible to readers.